# MS Teams Graph API: Get all teams user(s) are apart of

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to use the graph api to get the teams a list of users is a member/owner of. I am using this endpoint to pass the list of users, then select the properties of the group that I am interested in:

`/beta/users/$filter=id+in+('user-1','user-2','user-15')$expand=transitiveMemberOf($select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions,displayName,mailNickname)&$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions,displayName`

This will return a list of groups the member is apart of, including the Teams the member is apart of (up to 15 users). It will filter the groups to only return `id,resourceProvisioningOption,displayName` and `mailNickname`.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,resourceProvisioningOptions,displayName,transitiveMemberOf(id,resourceProvisioningOptions,displayName,mailNickname))",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "user-1",
            "displayName": "Jeff Smith",
            "transitiveMemberOf": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
                    "id": "directoryRole-1",
                    "displayName": null
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
                    "id": "directoryRole-2",
                    "displayName": null
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
                    "id": "team-id-1",
                    "resourceProvisioningOptions": [
                        "Team"
                    ],
                    "displayName": "My Team 1",
                    "mailNickname": "MyTeam1"
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
                    "id": "directoryRole-3",
                    "displayName": null
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
                    "id": "team-id-2",
                    "resourceProvisioningOptions": [
                        "Team"
                    ],
                    "displayName": "My Team 2",
                    "mailNickname": "MyTeam2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Since the user is apart of Azure directory groups, those are returned, but the `resourceProvisioningOptions` identifies if the user is on a team. In this case - 2 teams.

#### Problem

When looking in the Teams App, we see that the user is actually apart of the 10 different teams.

When calling this endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-1/joinedTeams` we see that the user is apart of 10 teams

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams",
    "@odata.count": 10,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "team-id-1",
            "createdDateTime": null,
            "displayName": "Team 1",
            "description": "Team1",
            "internalId": null,
            "classification": null,
            "specialization": null,
            "visibility": null,
            "webUrl": null,
            "isArchived": false,
            "isMembershipLimitedToOwners": null,
            "memberSettings": null,
            "guestSettings": null,
            "messagingSettings": null,
            "funSettings": null,
            "discoverySettings": null,
            "summary": null
        },
        {
            "id": "team-id-2",
            "createdDateTime": null,
            "displayName": "Team 2",
            "description": "Team2",
            "internalId": null,
            "classification": null,
            "specialization": null,
            "visibility": null,
            "webUrl": null,
            "isArchived": false,
            "isMembershipLimitedToOwners": null,
            "memberSettings": null,
            "guestSettings": null,
            "messagingSettings": null,
            "funSettings": null,
            "discoverySettings": null,
            "summary": null
        },
        ...
        {
            "id": "team-id-10",
            "createdDateTime": null,
            "displayName": "Team 3",
            "description": "Team3",
            "internalId": null,
            "classification": null,
            "specialization": null,
            "visibility": null,
            "webUrl": null,
            "isArchived": false,
            "isMembershipLimitedToOwners": null,
            "memberSettings": null,
            "guestSettings": null,
            "messagingSettings": null,
            "funSettings": null,
            "discoverySettings": null,
            "summary": null
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Questions:

1. Is there another endpoint that I can use to pass a list of users and get the teams they are owner/member of?
2. Why is the data different between endpoints

I am trying to avoid calling the `/joinedTeams` endpoint due to number of users and rate limiting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the /joinedTeams endpoint, but also put those calls in a batch to MS Graph.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

This would allow you to send a batch of 20 (i think) requests in one call to the graph making it much faster and less likely to be throttled.